# clojure "look-and say" sequence

Tags: clojure

Working on some [2015 AoC](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/10) problems to learn clojure... The below was quick enough for the 40th iteration, but crawls to a halt much after that.  I compared to a few other peoples solutions and it's not immediately obvious to me why this is so slow.  I tried to use recur believing it to be about as efficient as a loop (and to avoid stack consumption).  One thing I'm not 100% clear on is if there is a sigifnicant difference between just using recur, versus using loop recur.  I tested it both ways and saw no difference.

```
(def data "3113322113")

(defn encode-string [data results count]
   (let [prev (first data)
         curr (second data)]
     (cond (empty? data) results
           (not= prev curr)
           (recur (rest data) (str results count prev) 1)
           :else (recur (rest data) results (inc count)))))

(count
 (nth (iterate #(encode-string % "" 1) data) 40 #_50))
```

An example of a solution I benchmarked against is Bruce Hauman's, which is really nice:

```
(defn count-encode [x]
  (apply str
         (mapcat 
          (juxt count first)
          (partition-by identity x))))
```

I realize in my solution I am iterating over very large strings repeatedly, but I don't see how Bruce's is so much faster since although he is not explicitly iterating, partition is probably iterating behind the scenes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your version is computing something like

```
(str "11" (str "22" (str "31" ...)))
```

which is building up a brand-new String object for every two characters. Since this involves iterating over every character in the input and output strings at each step, your operation is quadratic in the length of the string.

The solution you're comparing to is different: it builds up a lazy sequence of integers, which is a linear-time process. Then, it does something like

```
(apply str [1 1 2 2 3 1])
```

which is the same as

```
(str 1 1 2 2 3 1 ...)
```

and `str`, when called with multiple arguments, uses a StringBuilder to efficiently build up the result incrementally, an optimization that is not available if you demand a full-fledged String object at every intermediate step. As a result, the whole process is linear-time, rather than quadratic.